# Fit Java Image into JFrame

Tags: java, image, swing, applet

I'm trying to display an Image that is bigger than the JFrame Dimensions.  If I try to resize the Image smaller, then the Image quality is lost.

If I make the Image larger, the quality is not lost. Is this normal behavior in Java image package?

I guess what I'm trying to figure out is that probably I'm doing something wrong when reducing the Image size.  So does Java provide a method to automatically do this without loosing image quality?

Same behavior like JButtons, where java automatically adjusts the space occupied by a JButton in a JPanel.

```
      bufferedImage = resize(bufImage,500,600);

    ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(bufferedImage);

    resizedIMage = imageIcon.getImage();
```

The actual resize is below.  I took it from the internet.

```
      private static BufferedImage resize(BufferedImage image, int width, int      height) {
        int type = image.getType() == 0? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB :     image.getType();
      BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, type);
      Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
      g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);

      g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
      RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);

      g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
      RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);

      g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
      RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

      g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height, null);
      g.dispose();
      return resizedImage;
    }
```

Comment: How are you trying to re-size it?  And how can an image fit into a smaller box if you don't make it smaller?

Comment: How would you possibly make an image smaller without shrinking it?  Crop it?

Comment: I see you've edited your question, but you're still not telling us how you're shrinking your images, so I don't know how we can provide an answer other than by guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Java 5 or newer you can try RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC for your interpolation hint.

There is a very detailed description of the different scaling behaviours of Java2D in this article: [perils-of-getScaledInstance](https://web.archive.org/web/20070913080726/http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html)

It contains examples of the different downscale results you can expect to see with the different approaches available in Java.

It also provides sample code that uses a multi-step aproach to downscale the image which appears to produce much better results than VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR.

Comment: Thanks the algorithm in that link actually provides good results when down scaling images.  This solved my problem.

Comment: Just wanted to say that in my case, every time I modified the image in any way (shrink, resize, ect..) the quality deteriorated in very small amounts. Noticed this after modifying image many times.  So I just kept an original copy of the image in memory and used that one instead.

Answer (score 1):

Override the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method of whatever component will display the image and look at Graphics.[drawImage](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage)()

You can even cast your `Graphics` instance into a [Graphics2D](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) for more functionalities. For example [setRenderingHings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#setRenderingHint)()

```
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
RenderingHints rh = g2.getRenderingHints ();
rh.put (RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
g2.setRenderingHints (rh);
```

Comment: But it is almost always better not to use paint and not to do this directly in the JFrame.  Better to do drawing in the paintComponent method of a JComponent held by the JFrame, often the JPanel that represents the JFrame's contentPane.

Comment: hence I said to override the method of whatever component

Comment: I would never recommend drawing directly on a JFrame or JDialog :)

Comment: In that case, can you change paint() to paintComponent()?  It is in the 1st sentence.

Comment: I usually use a JPanel for dummy drawable component.. but I'll make the correction in my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I would get rid of this:

```
int type = image.getType() == 0? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB :     image.getType();
```

And always use `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB`

That seems to give me good results.